# nsuserdefaults value getting replaced

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

Inside the same viewcontroller class i am using two NSUserDefaults,one for saving UISwitch state and  other one  for DatePicker value.
Here is my code :

```
-(IBAction) switchValueChanged
{
    NSString *value = @"ON";

    NSUserDefaults *userPreferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (switch1.on)
    {
        value = @"OFF";
        [userPreferences setObject:value forKey:@"stateOfSwitch"];     
        [switch1 setOn:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [userPreferences setObject:value forKey:@"stateOfSwitch"];

        [switch1 setOn:NO animated:YES];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    }
}

- (IBAction)scheduleTime
{
    NSDate *pickerTime=datePicker.date;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:pickerTime forKey:@"setPickerTime"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; 
}
```

Problem is, only nsuserdefault for date picker is working,other one is not working.I think NSUserDefault value of DatePicker is replacing UISwitch's NsUserDefault value.Can anyone help me to solve this problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
if (switch1.on)
    {
        value = @"OFF";
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:value forKey:@"stateOfSwitch"];

        [switch1 setOn:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:value forKey:@"stateOfSwitch"];
        [switch1 setOn:NO animated:YES];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    }
```

Comment: how to access value of NSUserDefaults please show me yourcode

Comment: NSString *_value= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"stateOfSwitch"];

Comment: try [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"stateOfSwitch"] let me known

Answer (score 2):

> NSUserDefaults caches the information to avoid having to open the
>   user’s defaults database each time you need a default value. The
>   **synchronize** method, which is automatically invoked at periodic
>   intervals, keeps the in-memory cache in sync with a user’s defaults
>   database.

Add a `[userPreferences synchronize];` invocation after the if/else block in the first function and try again.

Comment: still it is not working..

Comment: Are you sure you're getting it correctly?

Comment: yes,i am getting the same problem

Comment: Getting the value of `stateOfSwitch` correctly, I mean.

Comment: No..Even if i toggle switch value to ON,it is displaying OFF state(default mode)

Comment: You don't seem to understand what I'm saying. Somewhere in your code you're probably setting your switch to a default value (OFF) and not getting it from the `NSUserDefault`s.